# How can I count the number of elements that match my CSS selector?

Tags: selenium, css-selectors, selenium-rc

I am trying to use SeleniumRC to test my GWT App and am trying to match elements using CSS selectors.

I want to count the number of enabled buttons in the following HTML.

A button is enabled if it is under a `<td>` with `class="x-panel-btn-td "` and disabled if it is under a `<td>` with `class="x-panel-btn-td x-hide-offsets"`.

So basically, I want to retrieve the number of buttons under all `<td>`s with the class `x-panel-btn-td`.

```
<table cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td id="ext-gen3504" class="x-panel-btn-td ">
            <em unselectable="on">
                <button id="ext-gen3506" class="x-btn-text" type="button">OK</button>
            </em>
        </td>
        <td id="ext-gen3512" class="x-panel-btn-td x-hide-offsets">
            <em unselectable="on">
                <button id="ext-gen3506" class="x-btn-text" type="button">Yes</button>
            </em>
        </td>
        <td id="ext-gen3520" class="x-panel-btn-td">
            <em unselectable="on">
                <button id="ext-gen3506" class="x-btn-text" type="button">No</button>
            </em>
        </td>
        <td id="ext-gen3528" class="x-panel-btn-td x-hide-offsets">
            <em unselectable="on">
                <button id="ext-gen3506" class="x-btn-text" type="button">Cancel</button>
            </em>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: FYI, please scroll down to see my answer if you are looking for the Webdriver equivalent

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As far as I am aware you can't do this using CSS selectors, but there is a command in Selenium for counting by XPath. The following command will verify there are two disabled buttons:

```
verifyXpathCount | //td[contains(@class, 'x-hide-offsets')]//button | 2
```

In Selenium RC (Java) this would look more like

```
assertEquals(selenium.getXpathCount("//td[contains(@class, 'x-hide-offsets')]//button"), 2);
```

Comment: Accepting this as answer because this is more straight forward in selenium terms.

Comment: Useful, but the original title was asking for CSS equivalent, not XPath.

Answer (score 14):

This is now also implemented (without any extra Javascript magic needed) in [Selenium Webdriver API](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/Selenium.html)   Since google still links to this question as a top result, even though Selenium RC has been replaced by Webdriver, hopefully this saves someone time.

Example java code:

```
int locatorElementSize = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("yourCSSLocator")).size();
```

Answer (score 8):

With newer versions of Selenium, there is a function GetCSSCount(string locator). Just thought an update to this question would be useful

Comment: Anyone know which versions of Selenium in particular offer this? And in SElenium RC and WebDriver? Or WebDriver only?

Comment: Also, forgot to ask earlier, which versions of Selenium in terms of the server JAR, client code bindings, and/or the IDE.

Answer (score 2):

This should be relatively simple.  You can do it multiple ways but I would suggest using the `getEval(...)` in DefaultSelenium.

Write some JavaScript that:

1. gets all elements by id: ext-gen3506
2. iterates through all elements and checks to see if it's enabled
3. if it's enabled, increment a count
4. "return" the count.

Generally, `getEval(...)` will return the value of the last statement that ran... so that should give you the count.

Comment: the buttons wouldnt have same id... (i copy pasted tht button tag and hence the same id displayed in the code snippet. my bad.)

I should get all elements of type button.

Answer (score 2):

Since Selenium is part of Firefox and the latter is supporting Selectors API one could simplify counting matches of a CSS locator using a test like this:

```
verifyEval | window.document.querySelectorAll("your#css > selector.here").length | 4
```

In this example count is verified to be 4, of course.

Comment: Does this work for other browsers like IE? We'd ideally want a cross browser solution.

Comment: one thing to note about this method, unlike regular Selenium RC API commands, you omit "css=" as prefix for the locator.

Comment: Thanks @soletan. Good to know that compatibility matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution, using javascript, similar to post about Selector API / window.document.querySelectorAll:

http://blog.eviltester.com/2010/03/a-simple-getcsscount-helper-method-for-use-with-selenium-rc.html