# how to get count of all the child tags using selenium and css

Tags: css, selenium, selenium-rc

```
<div class="searchCenter largeFont">
<b> 1 </b>
<a href="/mytwonky/search/?p=2&q=next&mt=1"> 2 </a>
<a href="/mytwonky/search/?p=3&q=next&mt=1"> 3 </a>
</div>
```

How would I get a count of all the child nodes of `<div>`, in the above case there are three children of `<div>`.

What command would I use in Selenium using CSS selectors?

**I found the answer:**
I found the answer to my question and would like to mention below for future reference:

The above could be done by the following:

```
se.get_css_count("css=div#paginationContainer div[class='searchCenter largeFont']>*")
```

Comment: Perhaps off-topic, but in Javascript : `document.getElementById("myDiv").childNodes.length;`

Comment: In which case, you should **post an answer to your own question** and accept it yourself. That way, google will see the answer, plus you might get a few upvotes from it. :)

Comment: have you tried storeCssCount()

Comment: These are also helpful if one was using older version of Selenium w/o the CSS count method available: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573170/how-can-i-count-the-number-of-elements-that-match-my-css-selector and http://www.eviltester.com/index.php/2010/03/13/a-simple-getcsscount-helper-method-for-use-with-selenium-rc